# Call mySQL rows to a Flask function and run model on them, outputting the results to a HTML table?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, lda, topic-modeling

I want to call the rows of a column from a mySQL database table to my Flask application, so I can run my LDA topic model over them. I then want to print the LDA topics identified into a HTML table for the user to see. (I also want to visualise this data in the table, but that's another challenge). For now I just want to print the topics in a basic way.

When I run the code below and load my application, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Full traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeram\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\jeram\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\jeram\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\jeram\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\jeram\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\jeram\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\jeram\Documents\NCI\Semester 3\TriagatronX50\app.py", line 65, in insight
    new_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in resultValue]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is my Python function:

```
    @app.route('/insight', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def insight():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Main Themes':
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            resultValue = cur.execute("SELECT journal_entry FROM journals")
            common_dictionary = Dictionary(common_texts)
            new_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in resultValue]
            lda = gensim.models.LdaModel(new_corpus, num_topics=5, alpha='auto', eval_every=5)
            main_themes = pprint(lda.print_topics())
        # return render_template('insight.html', value=main_themes)        
    return render_template('insight.html', value=main_themes)
```

My HTML code:

```
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <table id=journallist>
                    <form method=" ">
                        <th>Topics Identified</th>
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ value }} </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </form>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Main Themes" class='btn'>
            </div>
```

Ideally I would also like to get my button working so that the function only acts when it is called, but firstly I just want to get it working at a basic level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing you want something like `new_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text[0]) for text in cur.fetchall()]`.  `cur.execute` _returns_ the number of row affected by a query (an integer), but you want the actual rows returned, which is the return value of `cur.fetchall()`.  And from each row you want the first (and only) value, `text[0]`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you for your comment! Sorry if it's an obvious question, but where should I specify from where I want to fetch the rows? If I leave the resultValue line of code in (having made the changes you suggest), I get this error: 'TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string'. But if I take it out, I get this error: 'MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: execute() first'

Comment: That error message might mean that it wants the `text` split into words, in which case `new_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text[0].split()) for text in cur.fetchall()]` _might_ work.  Or you might need to use a proper tokeniser.  You need to check the docs for your model thing to find out what it expects (data sci / NLP / sentiment analysis isn't an area I know much about).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I got it working with your advice, I appreciate the help a lot! Hope you had a nice new years :)